# Docker daemon json update in config vs docker desktop

Tags: docker

In `C:\ProgramData\Docker` there was no config folder for the Docker daemon, so I added one following these instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon

```
{
    "authorization-plugins": [],
    "dns": [],
    "dns-opts": [],
    "dns-search": [],
    "exec-opts": [],
    "storage-driver": "",
    "storage-opts": [],
    "labels": [],
    "log-driver": "",
    "mtu": 0,
    "pidfile": "",
    "data-root": "",
    "cluster-store": "",
    "cluster-advertise": "",
    "debug": true,
    "hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"],
    "log-level": "",
    "tlsverify": true,
    "tlscacert": "",
    "tlscert": "",
    "tlskey": "",
    "group": "",
    "default-ulimits": {},
    "bridge": "",
    "fixed-cidr": "",
    "raw-logs": false,
    "registry-mirrors": [],
    "insecure-registries": [],
    "disable-legacy-registry": false
}
```

Netstat shows nothing monitoring port 2375, and I can't telnet to it.

Then, in Docker Engine in the Docker desktop app, it shows the config file:

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": false
}
```

If I try to edit the file here, it allows me to edit it, but then Docker will not restart and I have to factory reset.

what is the difference between adding a config file to `C:\ProgramData\Docker` and editing the config file through Docker Desktop setting?